# How to open SharePoint files in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sharepoint

Currently we are using  IE 10 and IE 11 as the browser for opening the file, pages of  my SP 2013 site.Now customer wants us to  test the applciation in chrome also.  so, i installed  chrome  ver 33.0.1750.3 and tried to access the sharepoint site. but somehow its not opening. 
can anyone please tell whats the resolution. is there any settings in chrome i need to make such that it works just like IE 10 or 11

Comment: if you using chrome there should be no problem accessing sharepoint 2013 site, perhaps if you will provide more detailed error description you can get some advice

Comment: As Alexander mentions there should be no issue with opening the sites in chrome web browser.  You will not however be able to use the 'Open in Explorer' option in the 'Libraries' Tab on the site.  This only works in IE at the moment.

Comment: but  somehow, i am unable to access the  sp site in my local desktop in chrome browser. i am  using ie as default browser till now. but for the testing purpses i am forced to use chrome and i am getting this issue. my local desktop is a VM with Win server 2012 provisioned